# Конвертация .py с дополнительным файлом в .exe

Tags: python-3.x, exe

Есть файл `main.py`:

```
import settings
print(settings.word)
```

И файл `settings.py`:

```
word = 'Привет'
```

Файл settings.py предполагается как файл с настройками, которые можно будет менять, и эти изменения должны влиять на работу .exe

Чем и как нужно конвертировать такие вещи в .exe?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: «Это называется лоренцева инвариантность и ковариантность. Поищите в интернете статьи на эту тему — они помогут намного больше, нежели можем мы здесь, в комментариях».

Comment: Я загуглил, и мне почему то стало страшно

Comment: @SuddenDumb https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct :)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

PyInstaller замораживает (упаковывает) приложения Python в автономные исполняемые
файлы в Windows, GNU / Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris и AIX.
https://www.pyinstaller.org/

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

---

```
pyinstaller -c -F main.py
```

Проверено: Python 3.7.3,
pyinstaller -v   # 3.6

**main.py**

```
import settings

print(settings.word)
```

**settings.py**

```
word = 'Привет Мир!'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том, что файл settings.py должен быть своего рода конфигом, который можно менять. А в этом случае, при изменении settings.py, в exe-шнике никаких измененний....

Comment: Извиняюсь что сразу не уточнил, поправил вопрос